# Passing Keys in list throws warning

Tags: reactjs, key

I have started learning about react and have a question related to keys .
react version used is     "react": "^18.2.0".
Parent Component Code :

```
import React from 'react';
import Person from './Person';

const NameList = () => {    
    const persons = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Bruce'
        }
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'Diana'          
        }
      ]
      const personList = persons.map(person => <Person person={person} key={person.id}/>)
    return (
        <div>
            {personList}
        </div>
        
    );
};
```

The above line uses Person Component as child component

Below code snippet  in child component throws warning :  Person: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop

```
import React from 'react';

const Person = ({person,key}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>
          I am {person.name}. I am {person.age} years old. I know {person.skill}
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
};

export default Person;

export default Person
```

However if change the above lines to below . Then the warning goes . Can someone please help as why the key is not needed although react docs says that to identify list it should have keys ?

```
import React from 'react';

const Person = ({person}) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>
          I am {person.name}. I am {person.age} years old. I know {person.skill}
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
};

export default Person;
```

I was of the assumption that for list rendering key needs to be passed but on passing it gives the warning .

Comment: You need to show us where you use this `Person` component. It's also very likely that you don't need the `key` at all

Comment: I have added the parent component . Can you have a look .

Comment: Ok, makes sense now. You need to pass `key` prop when returning a list of components so React can tell first Person from second, etc. I highly recommend you take time to read https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists, it explains it better than I ever could.

Answer (score 0):

About the warning, make sure to not name props you're trying to access as `key` or `ref`, because these are reserved names that React uses internally. This is why you get the warning.

> "Most props on a JSX element are passed on to the component, however,
> there are two special props (`ref` and `key`) which are used by React,
> and are thus not forwarded to the component." - [React docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/warnings/special-props.html)

To answer your main question, `Key` serve as a hint to React but they don't get passed to your components (You don't need to define `key` as a prop in your child component). The `key` property is used by React under the hood and is used by React to aid the reconciliation of collections.

However, if you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name, let's say `index`, and use it as it fits.

```
import React from 'react';

const Person = ({person, index}) => {
    return (
      <div> //or you can use an unique id that exists in person object
        <h2>
          I am {person.name}. I am {person.age} years old. I know {person.skill} and my ID is {index}
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
};

export default Person;
```

Comment: Your answer completely missed the point

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I updated the explanation, hope this makes more sense :)